# Handling api response with bloc pattern with rxdart

Tags: flutter, bloc, rxdart

Im a bit confused on how rxdart works with bloc pattern. This is a code i copied from a youtube channel. Its a bloc that has a method which returns an API response. There's usually a **mapEventToState** method somewhere in the bloc but this one doesn't. I've added some comments to show what i understand and hope you guys can correct me. Thanks.

Source code: https://github.com/bilguunint/igdb/blob/master/lib/bloc/get_games_bloc.dart

```
class GetGamesBloc {

    final GameRepository _repository = GameRepository(); // defining the api repository

    final BehaviorSubject<GameResponse> _subject = BehaviorSubject<GameResponse>();
    // defining a behaviour stream which will give only the latest item/data 

    getGames(int platformId) async {
      GameResponse response = await _repository.getGames2(platformId);
      _subject.sink.add(response);
    }
    // this method fetches the api data but not sure why add response to the sink. Isnt sink suppose to be an event? The response is an api json data so it's a stream right ? 

   dispose() {
      _subject.close();
    }
   //closing the stream when not in use to prevent memory loss

    BehaviorSubject<GameResponse> get subject => _subject;
   // defining a getter to be used outside the class

}
final getGamesBloc = GetGamesBloc();
// I think this enables us to use the bloc as getGamesBloc ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of BLoC pattern is to separate business logic from views to keep the code clean, readable and testable. The `mapEventToState` has the responsibility of converting events to state and you can use any other alternatives to do that. In `Cubit` from `bloc` package we're defining functions to emit and change state.

```
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<int> {
  CounterCubit() : super(0);

  void increment() => emit(state + 1);
  void decrement() => emit(state - 1);
}
```

In the example you provided, It's defining a function which will change the state. So, as far as I know that's correct and it counts as a business logic component.

Comment: but what does  _subject.sink.add(response); do ?

Comment: For that you should be familiar with the concept of Stream and Sink in dart. You can read more in https://dart.academy/streams-and-sinks-in-dart-and-flutter/ @Grey